# Showing markers on google maps in plotly dash app

Tags: python, google-maps, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to find a way to plot markers with specific information on Goole maps inside a Plotly Dash app.

Is there a way to generate a figure in Plotly showing google map with information I want on top? Or some other method with an equivalent result.

I can generate an html page to produce the desired outcome using gmplot package. But I don't think I can use this html file in a Plotly Dash app, unless I am mistaken. I know some Python but not JS.

Simple example code of what I am trying to achieve is below:

```
path ="map11.html"
API_KEY = "VERYLONGAPICODEHERE"


gmaps_key = googlemaps.Client(key=API_KEY)

add_1 = 'London, UK'
g = gmaps_key.geocode(add_1)

lat = g[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
long = g[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]

gmap1 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(lat, long, 17, apikey=API_KEY)
gmap1.marker(lat, long, 'green', title="Map works")
gmap1.text(lat, long,  "Important Info Hero", color='#09541d')

gmap1.draw(path)

print('Latitude: '+str(lat)+', Longitude: '+str(long))
```

Thank you!

I have tried googling and searching stackoverflow for the right package to use but either it does not exist or I am not using the right key words.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you can do with google maps is what's only available on the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation), and from what I know, you can only use the Google Maps API using a [python client library for Google Maps Web Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) (which does not include rendering a dynamic map). Though you can use the python library to render a static map (That includes markers). But to render a dynamic map and plot a marker, you would either need to use Maps Javascript or Android/iOS Maps SDKs.

Comment: Thank you, Yrll, so it looks like I would have to learn some basic JS and imbded it in my Plotly Dash app? I have found a way to add mapbox plot based dynamic map: https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example-with-plotly-express but this would mean I will have to pay twise: once to google for getting geolocation for an address and and once more to Mapbox. That or learn some JS..

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not that familiar with dash. But one thing I know is that it could be against their ToS if you use Google Maps API with other products like MapBox. I'm not a legal expert so it would be better to ask one if you want to be sure and you want to use both. With that said, I'll try to take a look at dash and see if there's something.

Comment: I was wondering if what's the use of plotly dash on your implementation? I found some other [library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-plotting-google-map-using-gmplot-package/) that could do the same to the link you showed on your previous comment.